# Customized debian/control file: Dependency is not satisfiable (python3-psycopg2)

Tags: debian, ubuntu-18.04, apt

I want to install my own Odoo 11 Debian package on Ubuntu 18.04. Here's the "Depends" part of my debian/control file:

```
Depends:
 ${misc:Depends},
 ${python3:Depends},
 adduser,
 lsb-base,
 node-less,
 postgresql-client,
 python3-dev,
 build-essential,
 python3-babel,
 python3-dateutil,
 python3-decorator,
 python3-docutils,
 python3-feedparser,
 python3-html2text,
 python3-pil,
 python3-jinja2,
 python3-lxml,
 python3-mako,
 python3-mock,
 python3-passlib,
 python3-psutil,
 python3-psycopg2 (= 2.7.4),
 python3-pydot,
 python3-pyparsing,
 python3-pypdf2,
 python3-reportlab,
 python3-requests,
 python3-suds,
 python3-tz,
 python3-vatnumber,
 python3-werkzeug,
 python3-xlsxwriter,
 python3-yaml,
 wkhtmltopdf, 
 nodejs,
 npm,
 python3-pip,
 python3-venv,
 python3-wheel,
 libxslt1-dev,
 libzip-dev,
 libldap2-dev,
 libsasl2-dev,
 python3-setuptools,
 node-less,
 postgresql-10,
 nginx,
 python3-xlwt,
Conflicts: tinyerp-server, openerp-server, openerp-web, openerp
Replaces: tinyerp-server, openerp-server, openerp-web, openerp
Recommends:
 ${python3:Recommends},
 python3-pyldap,
 python3-qrcode,
 python3-vobject,
```

But, when I try to install the package using gdebi, I got this error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree        
Reading state information... Done
Reading state information... Done
This package is uninstallable
Dependency is not satisfiable: python3-psycopg2 (= 2.7.4)
```

This is the result of `apt-cache policy python3-psycopg2` (I have my own local repository for dependency sources)

```
python3-psycopg2:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 2.8.6-2~pgdg90+1
  Version table:
     2.8.6-2~pgdg90+1 500
        500 http://10.3.0.70/local-repo  Packages
     2.7.4-1 500
        500 http://id.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://10.3.0.70/local-repo  Packages
```

I really need to install only the 2.7.4 version of the python3-psycopg2 because the 2.8.6 version isn't supported in Ubuntu 18.04. How to solve this?

I have tried to change the dependency entry on the debian/control file by changing the python-psycopg2 version to (=2.7.4-1) and (<<2.8.0) but still not working

Comment: Try to uninstall it first: sudo apt remove python3-psycopg2 before reinstalling the right version

Comment: @sylvain already did it, still, the result is Dependency is not satisfiable: python3-psycopg2 (= 2.7.4)